# sql query: no payments in last 90 days

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a Client with many Payments.  How do I query to get all clients that have no payment records in the last 90 days?

```
clients
=======
id          integer
name        string

payments
========
id          integer
client_id   integer
created_at  datetime
```

Essentially the inverse of:

```
select *
from clients
inner join payments on payments.client_id = clients.id
where payments.created_at > utc_timestamp() - interval 90 day
```

Hopefully more efficient than:

```
select *
from clients 
where id not in (
  select *
  from clients
  inner join payments on payments.client_id = clients.id
  where payments.created_at > utc_timestamp() - interval 90 day
)
```

Comment: Is the last query running slowly or something?

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using?

Comment: @Oded: mysql; @Abe: haven't tried in production yet, but might resort to it if I have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure there's an index on `payments(client_id)`, or even better, `payments(client_id, created_at`).

For alternative way to write your query, you could try a `not exists`, like:

```
select  *
from    clients c
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    payments p
        where   p.payments.client_id = clients.id
                and payments.created_at > utc_timestamp() - interval 90 day
        )
```

Or an exclusive left join:

```
select  *
from    clients c
left join
        payments p
on      p.payments.client_id = clients.id
        and payments.created_at > utc_timestamp() - interval 90 day
where   p.client_id is null
```

If both are slow, add the `explain extended` output to your question, so we can see why.

Comment: Thanks, the exclusive left join seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from clients
left join payments on 
    payments.client_id = clients.id and 
    payments.created_at > utc_timestamp() - interval 90 day
where payments.client_id is null
```